# Characterization of the parametrizing spaces of quadrics

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^3$. They are parametrized by the points of $\mathbb{P}^9$ and the space parametrizing the quadrics of rank 1 (by the rank of a quadric I mean the rank of the matrix corresponding to it) is the Veronese variety in $\mathbb{P}^9$ (right?). What would then be the subspaces of $\mathbb{P}^9$ parametrizing quadrics of rank 2 and 3?

Comment: What do you mean "what would be the subspaces..."? Do you mean, do they have common names? NB these spaces are not varieties, as their closures both contain the Veronese variety.

Comment: @Travis The excercise, as formulated by my professor is, "Determine the parameterizing space of all the quadric surfaces of $P^3$ and the spaces of the quadrics of
ranks 3, 2, 1 respectively". I have the same problem in understanding what exactly is meant by this.